# Integration of Autodesk Forge API service with Streamlit

Tags: autodesk-forge

Pardon me if this is a dumb question! However, I am curious whether it is possible to use 'Streamlit' (https://streamlit.io/) app as the front end and Forge APIs as the back end. If this is possible; Could you, please show some examples of how to integrate Streamlit and Forge?

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit is in Python and there is [Unofficial Autodesk Forge SDK for Python](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-sdk-python), so you can easily get your data from Forge APIs and show them using Streamlit components.

I created a simple app which lists buckets, then objects in the selected bucket and shows details of the selected object.

[Streamlit with Forge sample](https://github.com/AlexPiro/forge-streamlit)